# Hibernate - Fetch data using in one to one relation

Tags: hibernate, fetch

I am trying to understand Hibernate logic with different relations and Fetch modes. My question is here:

There is a one to one Fetch.EAGER relation between Student object and Advisor object. What will be the result of below code if the no. 23 student and no. 25 student have the same advisor and why ?

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Student st1 = session.load(Student.class , 23 );
Student st2 = session.load(Student.class , 25 );

System.out.println(st1.getAdvisor() == st2.getAdvisor());
session.close();

session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Student st3 = session.load(Student.class , 23);
System.out.println(st1 == st3);

session.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(st1.getAdvisor() == st2.getAdvisor());
```

In your code output of the above line will **never be** `true` because `==` checks for same references.

What you are looking for is:

```
System.out.println(st1.getAdvisor().equals(st2.getAdvisor()));
```

Make sure you have `equals()` overridden in `Advisor` class (for example, comparing with primary keys).

Same goes for `System.out.println(st1 == st3);`